# Filter URL in GA regex for Custom IDs

Tags: google-analytics-filters

Looking to clear up some pages with IDs having trouble matching the ID in a middle of a URL.

Looking for some regex so I can do a find and replace so I can

Any help appreciated some examples are

```
www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/17986016/Kappa
www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/17982038/Kappa
www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/17870320/Kappa
www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/18982038/Kappa/?action=back
```

Note alpha, bravo and delta are static but Kappa is dynamic.

The ID changes but is 8 character long.

Would like to finish with:

```
www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/Kappa
```

Answer (score 0):

A search and replace filter won't work for this as there is a variable (Kappa) in the RequestURI and the replace field in the filter requires a string.

A custom advanced filter will work though

By default GA only reports the RequestURI portion of a url in the reports. Are there any filters already applied that change the default reporting behaviour so that the Hostname is prepended to the RequestURI?

Assuming there are no filters already in play... and that the query parameter is also not a variable...

**Filter Type** > Custom Advanced
**Field A -> Extract A**
RequestURI `^(/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/)\d{8}\/(\w+)(\/\?action\=back)?`
**Field B -> Extract B**
Leave blank
**Output To -> Constructor**
RequestURI `$A1$A2`

If there is a filter in place that prepends the Hostname to the RequestURI, then try the following instead and make sure this filter is placed lower in the filter order, after any other filters that change the default page reporting behaviour.

**Filter Type** > Custom Advanced
**Field A -> Extract A**
RequestURI `^(www.abc.net/Alpha/Bravo/Delta/)\d{8}\/(\w+)(\/\?action\=back)?`
**Field B -> Extract B**
Leave blank
**Output To -> Constructor**
RequestURI `$A1$A2`